# Which X Window system is installed on my server that would work with Xming

Tags: linux, x11, xterm

I would like to use Xming to connect a server and managed to get it to work. I am now trying to get it to connect to a different server but i am not sure which X Window system is installed. I tried it through putty and i get the following error/warning:

`/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67/bin> jvisualvm`
`/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67/lib/visualvm/platform/lib/nbexec: WARNING: environment variable DISPLAY is not set`

I have previously used a windows BAT script to launch XWindows - Shown below:

```
@echo off
SET LOCAL_HOST=localhost
SET PATH=C:\wresourcex\bin\Xming

SET REMOTE_HOST=%1
SET SCREEN=%2

REM Default to archie with screen 1
if "%1"=="" SET REMOTE_HOST=MySever.com
if "%2"=="" SET SCREEN=0

SET DISPLAY=%LOCAL_HOST%:%SCREEN%.0

REM For XDM logon just run this line
REM run Xming -query %REMOTE_HOST% -lesspointer -emulate3buttons

REM For SSH Tunneling use these 2 lines
rem run Xming :%SCREEN% -lesspointer -notrayicon -emulate3buttons
run plink -ssh -X %REMOTE_HOST% /usr/dt/bin/Xsession

REM Use this if want Gnome instead
rem run plink -ssh -X %REMOTE_HOST% /usr/bin/gnome-session
```

The above works in one server but not on the one i am using now. I have looked at both the /usr/dt/bin/ and /usr/bin folders and both program (referred to in the script) do not exist in those locations. I am guessing that i need to use a different program but how do i know which "Xwindow" program is installed on the server i want to connect to or does it matter?

Note - I do not have admin access on the server so cannot install anything.

Thanks

### Edit

I am trying to use the script shown above to log on to a machine but it does not work. The same script was used to connect to a different machine before and it worked.

The machine i am trying to connect to is a Linux server - See below:

`Linux abc 2.6.32-279.11.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Oct 16 08:03:36 PDT 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

On my Windows PC i have XMing installed - I have no idea what is installed on the Linux machine and what i need to look for to know if i can connect to that Linux server.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here. It seems you're using multiple machines but how? Please edit your question to explain clearly: what operating system each machine is running; how the machines are connected; what programs you're using on which machine; where you want their windows to be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

X might be a little confusing when it comes to "server" and "client". An X server is serving a display, keyboard and mouse to X clients which are programs running on the same machine as the X server or on some other machine in the network.

If you are sitting on a Windows PC running Xming then Xming is your X server. You tell X clients (programs) to connect to that X server by setting the DISPLAY environment variable pointing to the machine and display number. Yes, a single machine can have more than one X server running, they will then have different display numbers. Example:
`export DISPLAY=192.168.1.12:0`

Then we have ssh and its ability to do port forwarding. One special case of ssh port forwarding is the forwarding of X. For this to work, the ssh client needs to know which DISPLAY to connect to and the ssh server needs to allow X11Forwarding. With this kind of setup, DISPLAY might be set to something like localhost:0 on your ssh client machine and once connected by ssh the sshd server will set DISPLAY to something like localhost:10 on the Linux server machine. All X traffic sent to DISPLAY localhost:10 on the Linux machine will then be encrypted by ssh and forwarded to localhost:0 on the Xming machine.

My guess is that your working servers have X11Forwarding=yes in /etc/ssh/sshd_config but your problem servers have the default X11Forwarding=no. This could explain why the DISPLAY variable is not set when logged in by ssh even though the option -X or -Y was given to ssh. You could fix this by changing /etc/ssh/sshd_config, or you could manually set the DISPLAY variable to point to your Windows machine without tunneling through ssh.